# Xfce4 , centos6 индикатор раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: xfce, linux

Один из популярных вопросов в гугле интересует и меня, но немного с другой стороны. Раскладку клавиатуры я заставил меня через

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,ru(winkeys)" -model "pc105" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

А вот с индикатором пока ничего не выходит, что можно поставить для индикации текущей раскладки?

p.s. Только не надо мне предлагать поставить xfce4-xkb-plugin, под centos его нет и в помине. Попытка собрать вылилась в отсутствие libxklavier 5ой версии. Собранная руками libxklavier помогла собрать xfce4-xkb-plugin, xfce увидела апплет keyboard toggle, но он в свою очередь не видит ни клавы, ни раскладок, вообще ничего.. висит себе в трее и тупит (оно может и понятно, система виртуальная, физической клавы нет и в помине)

Comment: гномовский апплет пробовал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, долгие пляски с бубном привели к тому, что мое мнение о xfce4 на centOS это путь тупиковый в плане работы с разными раскладками клавы, но проблему решил. 1. Есть забытый богом проект xxkb. Это индикатор раскладок клавы, он ничего сам не делает, только показывает. Работает во всех (почти) оконных менеджерах чем меня и привлек. 2. Скачанные исходники этого проекта, не смотря на их аскетичность - не собирались ни во что вообще. Гугл лишь утвердил мою верю в древность исходников. 3. Был найден rpm пакет для alt linux, нужной мне битности и пр. Раскрыв его через rpm2cpio попробовал позапускать, с некоторым тюнингом конфига и путей - все работало прекрасно.  4. Из готовых бинарников, конфигов и картинок - собрал rpm для centos 6 x86_64 - [ссылка][1] 5. В xfce4 в общем автостарте для всех  (/etc/xdg/autostart/keyboard_layout.desktop) добавил ссылку на все это хозяйство        [ay@inetcafe ~]$ cat /etc/xdg/autostart/keyboard_layout.desktop        [Desktop Entry]        Encoding=UTF-8        Version=0.9.4        Type=Application        Name=keyboard_layout        Comment=        Exec=/etc/profile.d/keyboard_layout        StartupNotify=false        Terminal=false        Hidden=false        [ay@inetcafe ~]$ cat /etc/profile.d/keyboard_layout        setxkbmap -layout "us,ru(winkeys)" -model "pc105" -option        "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"        /usr/bin/xxkbвсе работает!![alt text][2]  [1]: http://www.kitlinkor.ru/files/shevtsov/xxkb-1.10-1.x86_64.rpm  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teRyM.png

Answer (score 0):

xfce4-xkb-plugin компилить религия не позволяет?

Comment: p.s. Только не надо мне предлагать поставить xfce4-xkb-plugin, под centos его нет и в помине. Попытка собрать вылилась в отсутствие libxklavier 5ой версии. Собранная руками libxklavier помогла собрать xfce4-xkb-plugin, xfce увидела апплет keyboard toggle, но он в свою очередь не видит ни клавы, ни раскладок, вообще ничего.. висит себе в трее и тупит (оно может и понятно, система виртуальная, физической клавы нет и в помине)

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже так переключаю раскладку, индикатором служит светодиод capslock. Переключаю тоже на capslock.